# After updating to iOS 6 all of the Cancel buttons are not working in sharekit

Tags: iphone, ios, sharekit

```
- (void)cancel
{   
[[SHK currentHelper] hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Above given is the code for cancel button on sharekit twitter form but it is not working. I believe it was working before updating to iOS 6. After updating to iOS 6 i replaced deprecated ones.

```
- (void)hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
if (isDismissingView)
    return;

if (currentView != nil)
{
    // Dismiss the modal view
    if ([currentView parentViewController] != nil)
    {
        self.isDismissingView = YES;
        [[currentView parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else
        self.currentView = nil;
}
}
```

I replaced dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES with dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil.

Now i noticed cancel button is not working in any of the form pinboardform, SHKShareMenu, Instapaper and in all others .

Anyone knows why after updating to iOS 6 this cancel button on Sharekit stopped working. On clicking the cancel button nothing happens.

Why is that. What is the reason.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: hello, did u finished the sharekit in iOS 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. It has to **presentingViewController** instead of parentViewController.

Below is the code

```
- (void)hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
if (isDismissingView)
    return;

if (currentView != nil)
{
    // Dismiss the modal view
    if ([currentView presentingViewController] != nil)
    {
        self.isDismissingView = YES;
        [[currentView presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else
        self.currentView = nil;
}
}
```

This change of code in SHK.m made all cancels working. Now all cancels are working in Sharekit.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

at the end of these two methods :

```
- (void)cancel {

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and :

```
- (void)save {
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In the `SHKTwitterForm.m`, it is working for me.